# Integral $\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+4\pi}\frac{e^{-A\cos(\theta)}}{B+C\cos(\theta)}d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any way of evaluating this little monster of an integral...or its approximation?

$$\displaystyle\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+4\pi}\dfrac{e^{-A\cos(\theta)}}{B+C\cos(\theta)}d\theta\qquad,\,A,B,C>0$$

Comment: It's begging for a change of variable $x=cos(\alpha-2\theta)$.

Comment: Why do you say *little* ?

Comment: The integrand is $2\pi$ periodic, hence its integral over any interval of length $2n\pi$ is the same. WLOG take $\alpha=0$.

Comment: An identity perhaps useful for $s>1$ is
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{s+\cos x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}$$